# How to create this type of JSON data from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to create a json object as follows from php. How could I do it. I'm using MySQL table to get data.

```
{
        "JSChart" : {
            "datasets" : [
                {
                    "type" : "line",
                    "id" : "blue",
                    "data" : [
                        {
                            "unit" : "1",
                            "value" : "80"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "2",
                            "value" : "40"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "3",
                            "value" : "60"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "4",
                            "value" : "65"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "5",
                            "value" : "50"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "6",
                            "value" : "50"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "7",
                            "value" : "60"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "8",
                            "value" : "80"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "9",
                            "value" : "150"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "10",
                            "value" : "100"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type" : "line",
                    "id" : "green",
                    "data" : [
                        {
                            "unit" : "1",
                            "value" : "100"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "2",
                            "value" : "55"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "3",
                            "value" : "80"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "4",
                            "value" : "115"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "5",
                            "value" : "80"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "6",
                            "value" : "70"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "7",
                            "value" : "30"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "8",
                            "value" : "130"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "9",
                            "value" : "160"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "10",
                            "value" : "170"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type" : "line",
                    "id" : "gray",
                    "data" : [
                        {
                            "unit" : "1",
                            "value" : "150"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "2",
                            "value" : "25"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "3",
                            "value" : "100"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "4",
                            "value" : "80"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "5",
                            "value" : "20"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "6",
                            "value" : "65"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "7",
                            "value" : "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "8",
                            "value" : "155"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "9",
                            "value" : "190"
                        },
                        {
                            "unit" : "10",
                            "value" : "200"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "optionset" : [
                {
                    "set" : "setSize",
                    "value" : "550, 300"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setAxisValuesNumberY",
                    "value" : "5"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setIntervalStartY",
                    "value" : "0"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setIntervalEndY",
                    "value" : "200"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setLabelX",
                    "value" : "[2,'p1']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setLabelX",
                    "value" : "[4,'p2']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setLabelX",
                    "value" : "[6,'p3']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setLabelX",
                    "value" : "[8,'p4']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setLabelX",
                    "value" : "[10,'p5']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setAxisValuesNumberX",
                    "value" : "5"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setShowXValues",
                    "value" : "false"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setTitleColor",
                    "value" : "'#454545'"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setAxisValuesColor",
                    "value" : "'#454545'"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setLineColor",
                    "value" : "'#A4D314', 'green'"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setLineColor",
                    "value" : "'#BBBBBB', 'gray'"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setTooltip",
                    "value" : "[1,' ']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setTooltip",
                    "value" : "[2,' ']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setTooltip",
                    "value" : "[3,' ']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setTooltip",
                    "value" : "[4,' ']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setTooltip",
                    "value" : "[5,' ']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setTooltip",
                    "value" : "[6,' ']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setTooltip",
                    "value" : "[7,' ']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setTooltip",
                    "value" : "[8,' ']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setTooltip",
                    "value" : "[9,' ']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setTooltip",
                    "value" : "[10,' ']"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setFlagColor",
                    "value" : "'#9D16FC'"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setFlagRadius",
                    "value" : "4"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setAxisPaddingRight",
                    "value" : "100"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setLegendShow",
                    "value" : "true"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setLegendPosition",
                    "value" : "490, 80"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setLegendForLine",
                    "value" : "'blue', 'Click me'"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setLegendForLine",
                    "value" : "'green', 'Click me'"
                },
                {
                    "set" : "setLegendForLine",
                    "value" : "'gray', 'Click me'"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Can any one help me to do that. If there any tutorials to follow. I want to use JSChart to plot data on my HTML.

Comment: Please help us help you by including what you have tried so far, or the parts of your existing code that you need help with.

Comment: 1. Build the the respective array in PHP. 2. Use `json_encode()`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php. Please put some effort into researching the problem before posting here. [so] is not an alternative for personal research...

Comment: I think reading the documentation is a good start http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way is to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function:

```
return json_encode(array('JSChart' => array(
    'datasets' => array(
        ...
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like below code to populate your json with PHP and MySQL:

```
$info=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
array_push($info,$row);
}
echo json_encode($info);
```

would return:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["firstname"]=> string(3) "foo" ["lastname"]=> string(3) "bar" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["firstname"]=> string(3) "foo" ["lastname"]=> string(3) "bar" } }
```

json:

```
[{"id":"1","firstname":"foo","lastname":"bar"},{"id":"2","firstname":"foo","lastname":"bar"}]
```